# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) -CentOS

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, watir-webdriver, headless

I get the error: `unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)` when I run this code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start

begin
    browser = Watir::Browser.start "https://google.com"
rescue Exception => e
    puts e
    puts "Exiting..."
    exit
end

browser.goto "http://google.com"
puts browser.url
browser.close
```

I am using: I am using Firefox version 38.7.0, Headless gem version 2.2.3 and Selenium-Webdriver gem version 2.53.0.

I have tried:

- Updating  selenium-webdriver
- Uninstalling headless, selenium and Firefox and reinstalling
  them.
- Restarting the server
- Updating Firefox to 45.0

The same code works fine in other test environments.

**Updates:**

I have tried running the same code with Chrome as suggested by a poster. I got the error message: `unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515`

Just to be sure everything is installed right I just ran the following:

```
yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb
```

Response:

```
Package xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.15.0-36.el6.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I also ran:

```
yum install firefox
```

Response:

```
Package firefox-38.7.0-1.el6.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Typically that exception happens when there is a Firefox/Selenium version mismatch, but it looks like you've tried using the latest versions of both. Does it work with Chrome?

Comment: No it does not work with Chrome. When I run the same code but use Chrome I get the error: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

Comment: That is definitely an environment issue, then. I haven't run on CentOS, but this is what we're doing to load browsers on Travis, which you might be able to duplicate to make sure that browsers and binaries are where you can use them: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that it was a user rights issue that was causing the problem. I logged in as the root user and was pleasantly surprised to see that the code ran without any errors.